# Data validation in Delphi using TField.CustomConstraint

Tags: delphi, validation, firedac

I'm using Delphi 6XE, with MySQL as database server.

I have table's fields as shown below

[image]

I'm using FireDAC.

[image]

I'm trying to implement data validation using `TField.CustomConstraint`, so I use the Field Editor to generate `TField` descendant objects as shown below

[image]

I have setup field's property using Object Inspector

With browsing from Google, and documentation, the authers give example to use like `CustomConstraint := 'x>1000';` I tried with `x` but all data were not displayed when running the program, so I switched to use *field name* instead. But anyway I still can input any data I want, no validations were applied at all.

[image]

Please advise how to setup data validation in Delphi.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the [`ConstraintsEnabled`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.ConstraintsEnabled) property of your `FDQuery1` component to True. The reference says the following about this property:

> Specifies whether the dataset performs constraint checking.
>
> Use ConstraintsEnabled to get or set the flag that controls the
>   automatic record-level constraints enforcement. When
>   ConstraintsEnabled is False (the default), the dataset does not check
>   Constraints. This allows the dataset to perform large data updates
>   without the overhead of checking constraints. When ConstraintsEnabled
>   is True, the dataset checks Constraints at the end of data editing
>   (Post / AppendRecord / InsertRecord).

Comment: Thanks, so sorry I didn't carefully read all sections about this topic, I will try this as soon as I get back to my office machine, I will let you know.